# Restore individual tables on Microsoft SQL Server 7?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

is it possible to restore individual tables from a full backup file of Microsoft SQL Server 7 (yes, I know this is really old, but our client can't upgrade for various reasons).

The total backup file is about 180GB in size and restoring the whole database once a week to a development server is not pratical, as it takes several days (literally). But for development, we'd just need some tables out of this huge file.

Is it somehow possible to extract only the tables we need from the backup file?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not quite what you're after, because I don't think what you're after is possible.

However you could place the tables in question into a different file group. Then when it comes to restoring, you need only restore the file group that relates to the tables.

[File Groups in SQL SERVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178410(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks that's a nice idea, unfortunately we can't change anything on the production server, the client won't allow us to do it. We just can access the evening full-backup.

Answer (score 1):

Not without 3rd party tools.. and I don't know of any off hand.

Or you export/import from prod the tables (or just new/changed data) you need

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid the answer would be similar to this, as I couldn't find anything like it on my own research.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using the Red Gate tools to transfer some tables between Db, and it works great. However, it's NOT free tool, you can download the 14-day demo to try it out.